# How to post back disabled form control in mvc

Tags: javascript, jquery, asp.net-mvc

I have a simple form the user fills out and when finished they press save and this submits the form back to the controller. This part works fine.

The issue is that one of the fields is disabled (read-only) which I populate using jquery dynamically based on other events happening on the screen (users selecting checkboxes and such). The problem is that no matter what data is in this field it will not submit because the control is disabled. If I re-enable the control the data is returned just fine.

How can I keep the control from being user-edited while still getting the data to post back? Short of writing my own submit method using ajax I'd like to use out-of-the-box form submit if possible. Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Disabled inputs will never post back to the server. You need to use a read-only input instead.

For example:

**Disabled:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @disabled = "disabled" })
```

**Read-only:**

```
@Html.TextBoxFor(model => model.Name, new { @readonly = "readonly" })
```

Comment: Changing disabled to readonly worked like a charm. Now if I can figure out how to submit a dropdown option I'll be set. Thanks

Comment: If it worked, choose this as the correct answer. Then, submit a new question for the drop-down list.

Comment: This works well for controls such as input type text, but radio, checkbox, select do not recognize readonly attribute however do recognize the disabled attribute. I've had to work around this before by removing the disabled attribute from all elements when the form is submitted. Not ideal but i needed other elements besides text inputs to be "disabled" $('form').submit(function () { $('[disabled]').removeAttr('disabled'); })

Comment: @SeanWessell, this works for drop-down lists as well. And, for radio buttons or checkboxes, you can always have a combination of a hidden input and a disabled radio button or checkbox. What you did with jQuery is not necessary.